# How do I check what the tag of the current GameObject is?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tags

I am creating a level select for my video game. I have 10 buttons, each with a different tag, and the each with the same script attached to them. In the script that's attached, I want to check what the tag of that Game Object is, and the print it on the screen.

This is the code I have tried-

```
if (gameObject.tag = "LevelOne") {
        Debug.Log("The tag for this GameObject is" + gameObject.tag);
}
```

However I get an error, because what I wrote is obviously incorrect syntax. **How do I check what the tag of the attached GameObject is? If not, what is an alternative to what I'm trying to do?** Thanks- George :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare variables with multiple `=` sign not one. When you use one `=` sign, you are assigning the value from the right to the variable in the left. In this case, the tag of your GameObject will be changed to `LevelOne` without the `if` statement.

```
if (gameObject.tag =="LevelOne")
{
    Debug.Log("The tag for this GameObject is" + gameObject.tag);
}
```

You can also make this code better by using the `CompareTag` function instead of `==`.

```
if (gameObject.CompareTag("LevelOne"))
{
    Debug.Log("The tag for this GameObject is" + gameObject.tag);
}
```

EDIT: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/200820/is-comparetag-better-than-gameobjecttag-performanc.html

Comment: One more thing, I know that this doesn't have to do with my question, but while you're here, how would i go about finding the gameObject's x position? Would `gameObject.transform.position.x;` work?

Comment: Yes, that work. Remember to assign it to something or you will get some error `float xPos =   gameObject.transform.position.x;`

Comment: Just added a link for CompareTag reason to be faster.

Comment: And how would assign xPos to the x position of another GameObject? I tried `exampleGameObjectName.transform.position.x = xPos;` but I get the error `Assets/Scripts/LevelTapScript.cs(21,39): error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of 'UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable
`.

Comment: Why not create a new question and put your code there. I will try to help. This question is getting longer and longer...

Comment: I asked another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044826/how-do-i-assign-a-gameobjects-x-and-y-position. Thanks for all your help with this question though. Cheers :)