# How do I assign a GameObject's x and y position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position

I am creating a video game in unity, and for the level select, I need to set the x and y position of a GameObject to the x and y position of a button.

I have tried this code-

```
if (gameObject.CompareTag("Level1")) {

        float xPos = gameObject.transform.position.x;
        float yPos = gameObject.transform.position.y;

        levelWindow.SetActive(true);
        levelTitle.text = "One- Dunes of Coral";
        levelDescription.text = "Begin your ocean voyage in the safe haven of the Hawaiian coral reefs...";
        levelWindow.transform.position.x = xPos;
        levelWindow.transform.position.y = yPos;
}
```

But I get an error like this-

> Assets/Scripts/LevelTapScript.cs(21,39): error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

My question is **how do I set the x and y position of the levelWindow (which is a game object) using my xPos and yPos floats?** Thanks- George :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a temporary `Vector3` variable, modify the x axis then assign it back to the `Transform.position`.

```
    if (gameObject.CompareTag("Level1"))
    {

        float xPos = gameObject.transform.position.x;
        float yPos = gameObject.transform.position.y;

        Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(xPos,yPos,0);

        levelWindow.SetActive(true);
        levelTitle.text = "One- Dunes of Coral";
        levelDescription.text = "Begin your ocean voyage in the safe haven of the Hawaiian coral reefs...";
        levelWindow.transform.position = newPos;
        levelWindow.transform.position = newPos;
    }
```

Note that z pos will be 0 when you do this.

Comment: Did You Mean To Set the Position 2 times or was it a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

One, for Unity questions, consider using https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Two, you can't directly set the position values of transforms.  What you have to do is something like:

```
levelWindow.transform.position = new Vector3(xPos,yPos,0);
```

Comment: Wow. I'm so stupid, I can't believe I forgot that. Also I will consider using GameDev. Thanks :)