# How do I get one game objects x position to equal another objects x position? (2D Unity Game)

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I have 2 game objects, one that is in a set X position and one that I was to spawn in the same 
x-position depending on. So Object1 has a set x position then object2 should find Object1's x-position to line it up properly.

Here is what I have tried, and it is not working:

```
 public GameObject LeftSpawn;
    public GameObject MiddleSpawn;
    public GameObject RightSpawn;
    public GameObject EnemyLeftSpawn;
    public GameObject EnemyMiddleSpawn;
    public GameObject EnemyRightSpawn;

    public GameObject LeftButton;
    public GameObject MiddleButton;
    public GameObject RightButton;

    private float pos1;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pos1 = GameObject.Find("Left Button").transform.position.x;
        GameObject.Find("Left Enemy Spawn Point").transform.position.x = pos1;
    }
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39044888/1134902) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the first one to the second one.
then in the `Update()` method use the `transform.Translate()` to change it's position to the other ones.